# ConfigurationManager handling Passwords between two Forms

Tags: c#, config, appsettings

I've got two Windows Forms `FormA` and `FormB` in one .NET Framework 3.5 project.

The Applications Main function(placed in Programm.cs) starts `FormB` after `FormA` stops:

```
Application.Run(new FormA());
Application.Run(new FormB());
```

`FormA` does the following to bring `FormB` the AppSetting `Password`

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config =
          ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("password", textBoxPassword.Text);
```

and nothing else :) I do not want to save the password in the app.config file.

Okay, Application starts, FormA() comes up and gets closed, FormB() comes up, tries to read `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Password"];` which is `NULL`.

How do I make this thing bringing me the Value I set in `FormA` instead of  `NULL`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share data between forms you can simply create a class with a `public static` property and use it to store your password.

```
public static class SharedData
{
    public static string Password { set; get; }

    // ... other shared properties

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will work - even if you load the configuration as you have done earlier in the form:

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["password"] = textboxPassword.Text;
```

in FormA

and

```
string pwd = ConfigurationSettins.AppSettings["password"];
```

in FormB

If you don't mind coupling your forms then there are other options, for example create a constructor for FormB that takes a password as a parameter, and call

```
new FormB(this.textboxPassword.Text).Show();
```

from within an override of the `OnClosing()` method in FormA.

--
my earlier answer missed the fact that you dont want to persist the changes.

Comment: but wouldn't it get into the app.config file? I do not want it to stay available in case the Application stops or crushes... @dice